# OpenERP: insert Data code

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I am new in OpenERP, I have installed OpenERP v6. I want to know how can I insert data in database? Which files I have to modify to do the job? (files for the SQL code)

Comment: you mean you want to configured sql server with openerp

Comment: I want to configure my database in openerp for a specific treatment. For example , i have to display only employees who have 50 years old. So I want to know where can I write my queries.

Comment: You can use Custom Filter to display record with age 50.
No need to write Query for that.

Answer (score 2):

The [OpenERP developer book](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/) is a good place to start. There's also a module called `base_module_record` that lets you make configuration changes and then export those changes as a module that can be imported to another database.

If you ask a more specific question, you'll be likely to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

OpenERP works with PostgreSQl as the Back-end Structure.
Postgresql is managed by pgadmin3 (Postgres GUI),you can write sql queries there and can add/delete records from there.
It is not advisable to insert/remove data directly into Database!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The addition of columns in the .py files of the corresponding modules you want to chnage will insert coumns to the pgadmin3 also defenition of classes will create tables...when the fields are displayed in xml file and values are entered to the fields through the interface the values get stored to the table values to the database...

Comment: Thank you all for the reply ; I just thought i should make my own query somewhere. Now I understand and I'll learn for more details . if you have tutorials that can help me I will be grateful.